# CSS Background Image Spans Only 960px

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS style here, but it spans across the whole screen rather than just repeating it within the 960px width of the body.

```
body
{
    width:960px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-image:url(logo.png),url(backgroundimage.jpg);
    background-position: top center, top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-attachment: static;
}
```

logo.png is just an image of a company logo, while backgroundimage.jpg is something I want to span only within the 960px rather than across the whole page. How can I do this?

Comment: `background-size: 100% auto`

Comment: Side-note: I don't believe that `background-repeat` takes comma separated shorthand, but I could be wrong. Being that the possible values (`repeat-x`, `repeat-y`, `repeat`, and `no-repeat`) already specify whether it should repeat along one axis, both, or neither, I'm not quite sure what the purpose of this shorthand would be.

Comment: Personally I'd strongly recommend not setting a width on body - create a div inside body and set that width to be 960px. While you can set styles on body directly, I don't believe it's advisable to set width here.

Comment: @Waxi This just makes it cover the whole screen I just want to have it only fit within the 960px

Comment: @Toby I only have a width on the body as this is the template I was given for this assignment

Comment: In that case, it should be `background-repeat: repeat-x`, without the `no-repeat` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a container class. This class will hold all inner div classes and content.

The code for this will be as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <style>
  .container{
    width: 960px;
    background: url("logo.jpg");
    height: 700px;
  }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

An easier way to do this would be to use bootstrap. The Bootstrap framework provides a .container class premade with custom responsiveness built in.

Comment: Ah perfect, this works out just how I need it to, thanks!

Comment: @Shiki glad I could help!